# Long exact sequence of the Klein bottle as a $S^1$-fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, higher-homotopy-groups

If we look at he Klein bottle $K$ as a $S^1$-fiber bundle over $S^1$, we can apply the long exact sequence in Homotopy for fibers. 
$$\pi_2(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_2(K)\rightarrow\pi_2(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(K)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow\dots$$
We can then easily see directly that $\pi_2(K)$ vanishes.

In particular we get the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(K)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow 0.$$Is that enough to deduce something about $\pi_1(K)$?

I know it is not the optimal approach but I am interestet in how much information i get out of the fiber bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduce for example that $\pi_1(K)$ is generated by $x$ the image of the generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$ by $f:\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(K)$, and $y$ the element of $\pi_1(K)$ whose image by $g:\pi_1(K)\rightarrow \pi_1(S^1)$ is the generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$.

To see this, let $z\in\pi_1(K)$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(z)=g(y^n)$, we deduce that $g(zy^{-n})=1$ and $zy^{-n}=x^m$, we conclude that $z=x^my^n$.

Comment: So i get by exactness the two generators, but the relator of the fundamental group can't be seen in that sequence?

Comment: It can be seen if you are able to describe the sequence more precisely,  remark that you also have an exact sequence $1\rightarrow \pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow \pi_1(S^1\times\pi_1 S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Thank you for that detail!